# Path issue when I try to rename an image

Tags: php

I want to rename images of a folder , try to test with one single image 
its showing Error saying.

> No such file or directory in..

I understand that there is a problem of path to the image , But I've tried many ways for typing the path.

> typing with **DIR**, dirname(**FILE**)

this is my code :

```
$dir = opendir(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'public'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'images'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'schoolIcons'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'room'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'run');       
rename($dir[14].'10101.png', 'aaa.png');
```

I've also tried typing :

```
$dir =  '../../public/images/schoolIcons/room/run/10101.png';
rename($dir, 'aaa.png');
```

And It Didn't work, always the same Path Error.

if I put `../../public/images/schoolIcons/room/run/10101.png` inside a img tag it shows the image , that's means that the file exist.
could you please help me to rename the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the file is accessible and doesn't need a permission to manipulate it.

Comment: thanks Lamine , its a permission issue + adding .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. after 'run'